# Why is the subjunctive used here?

Tags: subjonctif

On Quora a popular french writer wrote « Sauf qu'un pain qui ne soit pas de mie ou y ressemblant fortement, c'est quasi introuvable dans la majeure partie du pays.» Why have they used the subjunctive here when, from what I know, « sauf que » doesn't require it?

Comment: The sunbjunctive here is not required by *sauf que*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the author knows that the state of affairs being related has no reality (or practically none); therefore they treat it as a hypothetical fact. In fact the conditional (present) could also have been used.

- Sauf qu'un pain qui ne **serait** pas de mie ou y ressemblant fortement, c'est quasi introuvable dans la majeure partie du pays.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a le subjonctif parce qu'on est à la recherche de quelque chose de précis, il s'agit donc d'un souhait.

Autre exemple:

> Je cherche un appartement qui ne soit pas loin de la gare et qui soit
> lumineux. (c'est mon rêve = émotion= subjonctif)

Par contre:

> J'ai trouvé un appartement qui n'est pas loin de la gare et qui est
> lumineux. (fait réel)